# Can I open css pop-up from script?

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code which opens pop-up from a link:

```
<hr/><a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">Modal!</a><br/>

<!-- Modal -->
<a href="#" class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true"> </a>
<div class="modal-dialog"> ...</div>
```

Can I open this pop up from script i.e. something like this

```
if (document.help_form.username.value == "") {
    /* to make a popup here */
    valid = false;
}
```

Comment: how else could you open it up? css and html aren't  programming languages. they can't "pop up" anything. you HAVE to have a script to do that for you.

Comment: What makes this "pop up" in the first place?  Whatever code causes that to happen, you can invoke that code from other code.

Comment: @MarcB but the sample code pop up's without any script.

Comment: @David I think html5 and css3

Comment: @rozerro: Can you provide the HTML and CSS which produces this effect?

Comment: @David https://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-javascript-popup-window/   Modal – Pure CSS

Comment: @rozerro: not possible. there's SOMETHING there to make it happen, and it has to be javascript. html can itself can only pop up an entire new browser tab/window via `target="_blank"` on links, and css itself has no "popup" capapbility at all. it's just styling information.

Comment: I found this [article](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) then try change `window.location.hash` to pop-up from js

Answer (score 0):

Open from javascript:

```
function modalOpen(domId) {

  window.location.hash = domId;

}

modalOpen('modal-one');
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nreyo3sf/3/)

Answer (score -1):

You can open pop up using this below code:

```
$('#modal-one').modal('show');
```

Comment: please share a documentation link for this  `.modal` function

Comment: then you shoud mention in your answer "using bootstrap"